# Spivak Calculus on Manifolds, Problem 2-27

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

In the section on Partial Derivatives of Chapter 2, Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak, he mentions that the boundary of $A$ could be all of $A$ and Problem 2-27 shows one way of tackling this problem.

[image]

While it is not hard to prove 2-27, I don't think that I fully understand the advantage of doing this. Can anyone give a concrete example of using this method to solve certain optimization problems? Also, is $f$ required to be continuous in this question?

Comment: $f$ needs not to be continuous. This is just the set theoretical proposition that if the images of $g: U\rightarrow W$ and $h: V\rightarrow W$ together cover $W$, then for any $f: W\rightarrow \mathbb R$, its maximum is equal to the maximum of either $f\circ g$ or $f\circ h$.  It needs some more background to appreciate this result. Perhaps the decomposition and parametrization given by $g$ and $h$ can greatly simplify the expression of $f$.

Comment: @Justauser Thanks. Would you please provide some more background information? Any book or anywhere I can find some examples.

Comment: I don't really understand his intent. I guess it's something like, to do optimization on the sphere, one cannot take any derivatives, as the domain is not even open anywhere. But if we reparametrize the domain with new charts $U, V$, then at least most parts will be parametrized by interiors of $U$ and $V$, hence we can just do regular calculus inside $U$ and $V$. This shows why the idea of charts and (sub)manifold is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Just to try to make some sense out of this. Let's solve a really simple problem of finding the maximum of $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 2y^2 - z^2$ on the sphere. (You can use Lagrange multiplier, but that would require the function $f(x,y,z)$ is defined over a neighborhood of the sphere. Let's assume the function $f(x,y,z)$ is only defined on the sphere (abstractly, this is all we have when we don't have an explicit expression of $f$), and isn't extended to $\mathbb R^3$, so we have to solve the problem without going out of the sphere, which is in the spirit of intrinsic differential geometry.)

Then $f\circ g = 2x^2 + 3y^2 - 1$, with partial derivatives being $4x, 6y$. So the only critical point is $(0, 0)$, where $f\circ g = -1$. similarly $f\circ h$ has a unique critical point at $(0, 0)$ as well where $f\circ h = -1$. (This is indeed where the function achieves its minimum, not the maximum. So the maximum is actually achieved on the boundary. Similarly $f\circ h$ will not tell us about the maximum either, unless we are willing to work on the boundary, which will be a constrained optimization problem, much harder.)

We can also reparametrize (part of) the sphere using $(y,z)$ and the chart map $G(y,z) = (\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}, y, z)$, then $f\circ G = y^2 - 2z^2 + 1$, and the only critical point is $y=z=0$ where $f\circ G=1$. Then consider the chart $H(x,z) = (x, \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}, z)$, and $f\circ H = 2 - 2x^2 - 3z^2$ where the critical point is achieved at $x=z=0$, and $f\circ H = 2$ at this point.

This doesn't seem to do anything, but now we're confident that the maximum of $f$ must be among $-1, 1, 2$. Why? Because put all the charts we have used together, every point on the manifold must be in the interior of one of the charts, and $f\circ T$ has a maximum at an interior point, then the point has to be critical. This shows us how to use different charts to solve a problem (without ever worrying about the boundary or going beyond the manifold itself), so the idea of (sub)manifold, charts, etc are useful (if not natural yet).